# Excel Loop through Range- Charge Discharge of a battery

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to use excel to simulate the charging and discharging of a battery. As in once the battery reaches 1, the level of charge will decrease until it reaches 0 and then begin charging again back to 1.

I have tried using multiple IF functions that do not seem to be working as, for example:IFS(cell<=1, cell-10%, cell>0, cell+10%), the array will always continue to decrease or increase past 0 and 1 respectively and will never loop within the range.

Hypothetically you can say that it increases 10% an hour from 0-1 and decreases 10% an hour from 1-0.

Any help much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Sorry, i've specified the problem more clearly now

Comment: You missed the part where you need to provide the code you are trying.  It would also help if you mock up data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have something that tells Excel whether the battery charge is decreasing (draining) or increasing (charging).  Here is an example showing a possible solution.

Initial Setup:

- Cell C2 has the number `1` entered in manually
- Cell D2 has the word `Drain` entered in manually
- Cell C3 (and copied down) has this formula:

  - `=MAX(0,MIN(1,ROUND(C2+IF(D2="Drain",-0.1,0.1),1)))`
- Cell D3 (and copied down) has this formula:

  - `=IF(C3=0,"Charge",IF(C3=1,"Drain",D2))`

[image]